# how to make properties of an object update correctly when used in a new object?

Tags: javascript, object, oop

https://jsfiddle.net/ca4xvkzb/

```
    function foo(a,b)
    {
        this.a = a
      this.b = b
      this.bar = a+b
    }
    var z = new foo();
    z.a = 2
    z.b = 3
    console.log(z.bar)
```

what currently happens:

`z.bar` returns NaN, further testing implied that whilst `z.a` and `z.b` were having their values updated, `this.bar` of `z` was using the old undefined values for a and b, rather than the updated ones

what i need to happen:

`z.bar` should correctly return the value of `a+b`: 5, after they've been set after the objects definition, as i would like to use the `foo` object for more variables than just `z`

Comment: Either `z.bar` should be a function which calculates the sum when desired, or you should pass the correct arguments into the constructor function when `z` is created.

Comment: `this.bar = ()  => { return this.a + this.b }; console.log(z.bar())`

Comment: this.bar should be function like this and return sum from it

Comment: As the comments above already stated, `bar` should be a function. To zoom in a bit more: what happens now, is that `bar` is a value that is set to the sum of `a` and `b` , but only to whatever is passed to the function when calling it (or in this case in the constructor in `new foo()`. If you would say `new foo(2,3)`, `bar` would have the proper value, but it would *not* be dynamic, the value would be fixed. As Yogen showed above, a function is needed. Here is that same code in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/61to4eus/ (note the function call `()` after bar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like that :

```
function foo(a,b)
{
  this.a = a
  this.b = b
  this.bar = ()=> this.a + this.b
}
var z = new foo();
z.a = 2
z.b = 3
console.log(z.bar())
```

Comment: I am sorry, but had to downvote. This would require each use of `foo` to set `bar` *outside* the function. If you move the `z.bar=` inside the function as in (`this.bar=` ), it would make more sense. If you change that, I can remove the vote ;)

Answer (score 0):

As commented by walidum you are creating the `bar` function as a `ownProperty` of the `foo` instance. I think it would make more sense to include bar as a function of the foo class per `prototype`:

```
function foo(a,b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}
foo.prototype.bar = function(){ return this.a + this.b; };


var z = new foo();
z.a = 2
z.b = 3
console.log(z.bar()); // = 5
console.log(z.hasOwnProperty('a')); // = true -- because it's something that belongs to THIS very instance of foo
console.log(z.hasOwnProperty('bar')); // = false -- because the function does not belong to the instance, but to the class (all instances of) foo.
```